# Excel moving cell value down one row continually

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook where there are two cells, namely DX42 and DX43. These cells have values derived directly from a neighbouring sheet called RANDBETWEEN. The formula for DX42 is =RANDBETWEEN!A2 and for DX43 is =RANDBETWEEN!B2. In sheet RANDBETWEEN, there are two columns (A for DX42 and B for DX43) that span around 100 rows, full of numbers gradually increasing over time.

What I want to do is have a macro that will automatically shift the values of both DX42 and DX43 down one row every time I press a button. For example, I press once and DX42 becomes =RANDBETWEEN!A3 while DX43 becomes =RANDBETWEEN!B3. I click again and they become =...!A4 and =...!B4 etc etc.

If it is not possible to shift both cells at the same time, I'm fine with having two separate buttons (one for DX42 and one for DX43) that shift their respective values individually.

Also, the macros I've already tried (without success) take me into sheet RANDBETWEEN every time I click the button. I would prefer to remain in sheet1 (my main sheet) while the macro does its thing, so that I can continuously press the button without having to navigate back from RANDBETWEEN to sheet1 every time I do.

Can anyone help me out?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try associating this sub procedure with a button,

```
sub shiftDXdown()
    range("DX42").formula = _
        "=" & worksheets("randbetween").range(mid(range("DX42").formula, 2)).offset(1, 0).address(external:=true)
    range("DX43").formula = _
        "=" & worksheets("randbetween").range(mid(range("DX43").formula, 2)).offset(1, 0).address(external:=true)
end sub
```

It would be better if a proper parent worksheet reference was available for DX42 and DX43 but I would imagine you are putting this into the parent worksheet's private code sheet.